# TSQL Change grouping / count based upon dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have this very simple query:

```
SELECT
   Team.Code,
   COUNT(Task.TaskID)
FROM Tasks Task
LEFT JOIN Teams AS Team
ON teamid = task.teamid
WHERE....

GROUP BY Team.Code ORDER BY Team.Code
```

This produces for me a nice count how many task each team has. Cool.

Now I need to take it one step further and implement some business rules for the dates of these tasks.

First Compare the date closed with date signed off and take earlier of the two.
Take the above date (the earlier one) and compare it to the due date to see if less or equal.

If less or equal include in count. If greater than due date don't count it.

Now I'm not really sure how to structure this query so any pointers in how to incorporate the biz rules would be greatly appreciated.

> I'm Sorry guys. Not enough information totally my fault.

Vasanth the dates are ALL held in the tasks table.

Bummi. I'll get some metadata whipped out and posted shortly.

Comment: You're assuming information that we lack,could describe in more detail the structures and the desired result.

Comment: Which table holds DateClosed, DateSignedOff & DueDate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will get you started with your biz rules.

Query:

```
select 
       Teams.Code,
       count(Tasks.TaskID)
from
     Tasks
     inner join Teams on Teams.TeamID = Tasks.TeamID
     inner join (
                     select TeamID, min(case when DateClosed < DateSignedOff then DateClosed  else DateSignedOff  end) MinDateNeeded
                     from Tasks
                     group by TeamID
                ) as FirstCondition on FirstCondition.TeamID = Teams.TeamID
where
   Tasks.DueDate >= FirstCondition.MinDateNeeded
group by
   Teams.Code
```

Comment: Ahhh I can join to a sub-query